# ngbpopover placement always showing left in angular9 using bootstrap@4.5

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular9

I am using ngbPopover bootstrap in my application, I have upgraded my App from 5 to 9 version and updated bootstrap version 4.5 and @ng-bootstrap6. After upgrade this popover is always displaying left. I tried changing placement options but no use.

how can i move it to right ? did any one face similar kind of issues ? I tried installing popover.js and J QUERY as well but no use. always placement stick to left.

```
<li class="nav-item main-menu-right-option">
          <a class="nav-link link-icon" href="javascript: void(0)" [ngbPopover]="alertsModal" #popoverAlert="ngbPopover" placement="bottom-right">
            <i class="icon icon-alert">
              <span class="icon icon-dot icon-custom-dot"></span>
            </i>
            <span class="d-inline-block d-sm-none nav-link-text">Alert</span>
          </a>
</li>
<ng-template #alertsModal let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="modal-title align-self-center">alerts</div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Please let me know if needed any more details.

Thank you,
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

I was missing autoClose option in html and there is texttransform style overriding ngbpopover styles in my project.
I added autoClose as false and removed texttransform styles. working as expected.

Thank you.